# contains in xsl for multiple strings

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a variable which can come with different strings

Like error  = Remote error/Connection failed/ Connection Timeout/ Backend unavailable

```
 contains($error, 'Backend') or contains($error, 'Remote') or contains($error, 'Connection')
```

In xsl is there a way to do all three in single contains instead of multiple times which does *or* functionality

can I do this 
`contains($error, 'Backend|Remote|Connection')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reverse the `contains` test:

```
contains(concat('/Remote error/',
                '/Connection failed/',
                '/Connection Timeout/',
                '/Backend unavailable/'),
         $error)
```

Standard (unextended) XSLT 1.0 does not have regular-expression support, so `contains($error, 'Backend|Remote|Connection')` will not work as desired.

Comment: what about in xslt 2.0?

Comment: The contains() function works the same way in 2.0 as in 1.0; the 2.0 matches() function can be used to simplify the kind of multiple-string test you have (as can XPath 2.0 quantified expressions).  Check out the [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) and [XPath ... Functions and Operators](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/) specs.